# Create a new Webshop Parameter

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am very new to hybris e-commerce software and trying to learn with the help of wiki documents provided with it.I am trying to create a new Webshop parameter with three options so I can choose any one of then by HMC. I have changed the items.xml and created a enum and a new attribute in Basestore but on HMC name of new parameter is not proper its taking qualifier name appended with "[" can anyone suggest why it is happening and how to define name of new parameter.

Answer (score 4):

1) myextension-items.xml

```
<itemtype code="MyType" extends="BaseType">
    <attributes>
        <attribute qualifier="attr1" type="java.lang.String">
            <persistence type="property" />
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

2) localization\myextension-locales_en.properties (or other: _fr, _de, etc)

```
type.MyType.name=My Type name
type.MyType.description=My Type description
type.MyType.attr1.name=Attribute 1 name
type.MyType.attr1.description=Attribute 1 description
```

Comment: Thanks Lena i will try to do same. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        p {

            position: relative;
            left: 60px;
        }
    </style>


</head>

<body>
    <h2>Pizzahut</h2>



    <div id="container">

        <label>Megnevezés</label><br>
        <input id='Megnevezes' type="text"><br>
        <label>Pizza mérete</label><br>
        <select id="pizzameret" name="pizzameret" >
            <option>S</option>
            <option>L</option>
            <option>XL</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Egységár</label><br>
        <input id='Egysegar' type="number"><br>
        <label>Fénykép</label><br>
        <input id='fenykep' type="text"><br>
        <button onclick="pizzaHozzaad()">Feltöltés</button>
        <!--fügvényhívás-->
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>


    <div id="tablaParent">

    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="kosarTartalma">
        <p>Kosár tartalma</p>

         <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>pizzameret</th>
                    <th>megnevezes</th>
                    <th>egysegar</th>
                    <th>fenykep</th>
                </tr>
                <!--
                <tr>
                    <th><input id="idSzuro" /></th>
                    <th>
                        <select id="pizzameretSzuro">
                            <option>S</option>
                            <option>L</option>
                            <option>XL</option>
                        </select>
                    </th>
                    <th><input id="megnevezesSzuro" /></th>
                    <th><input id="egysegarSzuro" /></th>
                    <th><input id="fenykepSzuro" /></th>
                </tr>
                -->
            </thead>
            <tbody id="kosarBody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" , src="pizza.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" , src="webshoplogika.js"></script>
</body>

</html>






function Pizza(id,megnevezes,egysegar,fenykep,pizzameret)

{

    this.id=id;
    this.pizzameret=pizzameret;
    this.megnevezes = megnevezes;
    this.egysegar = egysegar;
    this.fenykep = fenykep ;
}












"use strict"


var termekek = [];
var tablazatParent = "";

var kosar = [];

var novekvo = true;


termekek.push(new Pizza(1, "pizza1", 600, "kamu.jpg","xl"));
termekek.push(new Pizza(2, "pizza2", 100, "kamu.jpg","xl"));
termekek.push(new Pizza(3, "pizza3", 200, "kamu.jpg","xl"));
termekek.push(new Pizza(4, "pizza4", 4000, "kamu.jpg","xl"));
termekek.push(new Pizza(5, "pizza5", 5000, "kamu.jpg","xl"));
termekek.push(new Pizza(6, "pizza5", 12000, "kamu.jpg","xl"));


var pizzameret = document.getElementById("pizzameret");
var Megnevezes = document.getElementById("Megnevezes");
var Egysegar = document.getElementById("Egysegar");
var fenykep = document.getElementById("fenykep");
var id = 6;
window.addEventListener('load', Window_Load_Handler, false);


function Window_Load_Handler() {
    tablazatParent=document.getElementById("tablaParent");
    tablazatRajzoloFuggveny(termekek);
}
function pizzaHozzaad() {
    id++;
    var pizzaNev = Megnevezes.value;
    var pizzaAr = Egysegar.value;
    var fenykepURL = fenykep.value;
    var ujPizza = new Pizza(id, pizzaNev, pizzaAr, fenykepURL);
    termekek.push(ujPizza);
    console.log(ujPizza);
    tablazatFrissites();
}







function tablazatRajzoloFuggveny(inputArray) { /* ugy kell meghivni, masik gombnyomasra,hogy at kell adnunk neki paratmeterkent egy tombot,
    amivel megmondjuk melyik tombbol szeretnenk tablazatot csinalni */
    var tablazat = document.createElement('table')
    tablazat.setAttribute("border", "true");                                                   /* a tablazatot hozza letre */
    var sor = document.createElement('TR');         /* a sort hozza letre */

    for (var k in inputArray[0]) {
        var cella = document.createElement('TH') /*create elementtel keszitettunk egy header cellat */
        cella.innerText = k;
        cella.addEventListener('click', rendezd , false);
        sor.appendChild(cella); /* cellat felakasztja a sorra */
    }

    var btnCella = document.createElement('TH'); // gombot kreálunk
    btnCella.innerText = "Kosárba";
    sor.appendChild(btnCella);
    tablazat.appendChild(sor);

    var btnCella = document.createElement('TH'); // gombot kreálunk
    btnCella.innerText = "Törlés";
    sor.appendChild(btnCella);
    tablazat.appendChild(sor);


    var sor = document.createElement('TR');
    for (var k in inputArray[0]) {
        var cella = document.createElement('TH') /*create elementtel keszitettunk egy header cellat */
        if (k == "pizzameret") {
            var szuro = document.createElement('SELECT');
            szuro.id= k
            var optionXL = document.createElement('OPTION')
            optionXL.text = 'XL'
            optionXL.value = 'XL'
            var optionL = document.createElement('OPTION')
            optionL.text = 'L'
            optionL.value = 'L'
            var optionS = document.createElement('OPTION')
            optionS.text = 'S'
            optionS.value = 'S'
            szuro.appendChild(optionXL)
            szuro.appendChild(optionL)
            szuro.appendChild(optionS)
            szuro.addEventListener('change', szurd , true);
            cella.appendChild(szuro)
        } else {
            var szuro = document.createElement('INPUT');
            szuro.id= k
            szuro.addEventListener('focusout', szurd , true);
            cella.appendChild(szuro)
        }

        sor.appendChild(cella); /* cellat felakasztja a sorra */
    }




    tablazat.appendChild(sor); /* sort felakasztja a tablara */
    document.body.appendChild(tablazat);


    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        var sor = document.createElement('TR');         /* a sort hozza letre */

        for (var k in inputArray[i])    {
            var cella = document.createElement('TD') /*create elementtel keszitettunk egy header cellat */
            cella.innerText = inputArray[i][k];  /*aktualis auto k kulcsai, value-jat olvassa be */
            sor.appendChild(cella);
        }
        var btnCella = document.createElement('TD'); // gombot kreálunk
        btnCella.innerHTML = "";
        sor.appendChild(btnCella);
        tablazat.appendChild(sor);

        tablazat.appendChild(sor);

        var kosarbaBtn = document.createElement('input');
        kosarbaBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        kosarbaBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Kosárba');
        kosarbaBtn.setAttribute('termekID',inputArray[i].id );
        kosarbaBtn.addEventListener('click', Kosarba_Click_Handler , false);

        var torolBtn = document.createElement('input');
        torolBtn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        torolBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Torlés');
        torolBtn.setAttribute('termekID',inputArray[i].id );
        torolBtn.addEventListener('click', toroldasort , false);
        btnCella.appendChild( kosarbaBtn);

        var btnCella = document.createElement('TD'); // gombot kreálunk
        btnCella.appendChild( torolBtn);
        sor.appendChild(btnCella);
        tablazat.appendChild(sor);

        tablazat.appendChild(sor);
    }
    tablazatParent.appendChild(tablazat);

}

function toroldasort(){
    var btn = event.target;
    var id = btn.getAttribute('termekID');
    console.log("termek id:" + btn.getAttribute('termekID'));
    for( var i = 0; i < termekek.length; i++){ 
        if ( termekek[i].id == id ) {
            console.log("lofasz");
            termekek.splice(i, 1);
          break; 
        }
    }
    tablazatFrissites();
}

function tablazatFrissites() {
    //var tablazatParent=getElementById('tablazat'); //feltetteük a tetejére
    var nodeTermekLista = document.querySelector('#tablaParent');
    nodeTermekLista.innerText='';
    tablazatRajzoloFuggveny(termekek);

}

function rendezd() {
    var header = event.target
    var attr = header.innerText
    console.log(attr); // ha igy mukodik akkor nem is kell gomb se input type legyen stb. próba cseresznye
    // fasza, megy, akkor folytassuk, ugye rendezni kell a szerint az attributum szerint amit megnyomtunk
    // ez most csökkenő sorrendbe rendezi az oszlopokat (már amennyi értelme van ennek stringek esetében)
    termekek.sort(function(a, b){
        //console.log(a[attr])
        // na mindegy, eddigiek alapján a ciklussal láttuk h kell kiszedni egy ojjektum mezejét
        // á faszom, kell erre legyen vmi egyszerű megoldás
        console.log(a[attr] +' '+ b[attr])
        // ez ugye számokra jó de stringekre nem
        if (novekvo) {
            if (a[attr] < b[attr])
                return -1;
            if (a[attr] > b[attr])
                return 1;
        } else {
            if (a[attr] < b[attr])
                return 1;
            if (a[attr] > b[attr])
                return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    })
    novekvo = !novekvo
    console.log(novekvo)
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value
    // fasza, műxik, látszik a termékeken h most csökkenő sorrendben vannak
    // ja igen és még ki kell rajzolni
    tablazatFrissites()
}

function szurd() {
    var szurtTermekek = []

    var asd = event.target
    console.log(termekek)

    for (var i = 0; i < termekek.length; i++) {
        console.log(termekek[i][asd.id]+' '+asd.value)
        if (termekek[i][asd.id] == asd.value) {
            console.log(termekek[i][asd.id])
            szurtTermekek.push(termekek[i])
        }
    }
    console.log(szurtTermekek)

    if (szurtTermekek.length > 0) {
        var nodeTermekLista = document.querySelector('#tablaParent');
        nodeTermekLista.innerText='';
        tablazatRajzoloFuggveny(szurtTermekek)
    }
}

function Kosarba_Click_Handler() {

    var btn = event.target;
    var id = btn.getAttribute('termekID');
    console.log("kosarba termek id:" + btn.getAttribute('termekID'));
    var valasztottTermek;
    for( var i = 0; i < termekek.length; i++){ 
        if ( termekek[i].id == id ) {
            valasztottTermek = termekek[i];
            console.log("kosarba!!");
          break; 
        }
    }

    var kosarLista = document.querySelector('#kosarBody');

    var sor = document.createElement('TR');
    for (var k in valasztottTermek)    {
        var cella = document.createElement('TD') 
        cella.innerText = valasztottTermek[k];  
        sor.appendChild(cella);
    }

    kosarLista.appendChild(sor);
}
```

Comment: It's unclear how this blob of HTML answers the question. Please see [answer].